# Expand Laravel 6 Login Form

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i am new to Laravel 6 and i did some tutorials to learn it.
Now i build a little Web-App for exercise.
I want to display a school with their teachers and their students.

So i created the table 'school'

```
Schema::create('school', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_user_id')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

and changed the User Table that comes with laravel ui

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('school_id');
            $table->foreign('school_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('corps')
                    ->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

And i build the School Model

```
class Corp extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Build SchoolFactory and UserFactory and i can seed my tables correct.

Now i want to expand the Login Form and the login validation. But i dont find the right place to overwrite the login logic.

Can sb. help me :)

Comment: How do you exactly want to expand the login form?

Comment: I want to expand it with the School name.

Comment: I'm just checking if I understand the question: so when a person is logging in, you wish to make him enter his name, school name and password?

Comment: Yes, in the future i want to have many schools with many teachers with many students..